# How can I replace @mention in java or c#

Tags: java, c#, android, replace, mention

I want to replace a string that contains many mention with a link

```
string comment = "@David you are best friend of @fri.tara3 and best of @mahta_";

string  pattern = "@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+?(?![a-zA-Z0-9_.])";
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<a href="http://Domain.com/David">@David</a> you are best friend of <a href="http://Domain.com/fri.tara3_">@fri.tara3_</a>
```

By the way , I don't want to use for or foreach...

Thank you very much

Comment: Please select one language only and show us what you've tried

Comment: Which is it, Java or C#?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: it's not important , I just want to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Java regex solution:

```
String str = "@David you are best friend of @fri.tara3 and best of @mahta_";
String formatted = str.replaceAll("@([^\\s]+)", "<a href=\"http://Domain.com/$1\">$0</a>");
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://Domain.com/David">@David</a> you are best friend of <a href="http://Domain.com/fri.tara3">@fri.tara3</a> and best of <a href="http://Domain.com/mahta_">@mahta_</a>
```